# How can I make an case statement to set a cash cap for a particular person in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case-statement

So I am working on a compensation report and one of the requirements is that One particular person has a different cash cap than everyone else. My solution was instead of making a parameter I want to make a query that the output is dependent on the person. EX) if person= particular person than cash cap = 15,000
otherwise cash cap=10000. This is what I have so far but it gives me an error.

[my code]

[image]

error message

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this syntax issue. Im still new to sql so Im not too sure.

Comment: Ugh... image of code. I don't see it from where I am, so I can't help. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the expression :

```
(case when mc = 'shaun meller' then 15000 else 10000 end) as cashcap
```